# How is this a Banach space?

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $k>0$ and $X=\{u\in C([0,+\infty); \sup_{t\geq 0}e^{-kt}\|u(t)\|<\infty\}.$  It is written in the book of Brezis that "It is easy to check that $X$ is a Banach space for the norm $\|u\|_X=\sup_{t\geq 0}e^{-kt}\|u(t)\|.$" This is not really easy for me to check. How is this true?

Comment: Well, what **are** the requirement for a "Banach space"?

Comment: If $(u_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in this space, then $(e^{-k\cdot}u_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in each $C[0,N]$. What can you infer from that?

Comment: It is positive, and it is 0 iff $u \equiv 0$. It is of course $\mathbb R$-linear. In order to prove the triangular inequality use that $sup(a+b) \leq sup (a) + sup (b)$

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp if the interval is reduce to $[0,N]$, it is obvious that this norm is equivalent to the sup norm. How however to this may not be the case for $[0,+\infty)$. How to move from   $[0,N]$ to $[0,+\infty)$ is my major problem.

Comment: @Maffred I dont have any problem showing that it is a normed space. The problem is showing completeness.

Comment: For each $N$ you get a limit $f_N$ on $[0,N]$. Now prove that $f_M|[0,N] = f_N$ for $M > N$ (so, you have the pointwise limit $f$ on $\mathbb R$) and that $f$ is contained in $X$ (because $(u_n)$ is bounded in $X$). It only remains to show that $u_n\to f$ in $X$.

Comment: Alternatively, it is straightforward to check that multiplication by $e^{-kt}$ defines an isomorphism of normed linear spaces from $(X, \| \cdot \|_X)$ to $C([0, \infty)$ with the sup norm. Hence, completeness of $(X, \| \cdot \|_X)$ follows from completeness of $(C([0, \infty)),$ sup norm$)$.